# All MySQL output rows are duplicated

Tags: mysql

For some reason, my SELECT query is returning duplicates of every row. Here's a brief breakdown of my tables:

**products:** products_id | master_categories_id | products_model | products_status | products_quantity
**categories:** categories_id | parent_id
**categories_descriptions:** categories_id | categories_name

This query works no problem...

```
***QUERY***
SELECT
  categories_name AS category,
  products_model AS model,
  products_status AS status,
  products_quantity AS qty
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN categories c
ON c.categories_id = p.master_categories_id
LEFT JOIN categories_description cd
USING (categories_id)
WHERE p.products_quantity > 0
AND p.products_status = FALSE;


***OUTPUT***
+-------------+------------------------+--------+-----+
| category    | model                  | status | qty |
+-------------+------------------------+--------+-----+
| Network     | CP-C-10-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Network     | CP-C-03-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Batteries   | BATT-LHP203            |      0 |   1 |
| Batteries   | BATT-LIB201            |      0 |   1 |
| Refurbished | UC*DELL-OPT-760-DC-IBC |      0 |   9 |
| Desktop     | HDD-320-SATA-3.5-PULL  |      0 |  12 |
| Refurbished | UL*ASUS-S56CM-SH51     |      0 |   1 |
+-------------+------------------------+--------+-----+
```

However, the categories table contains a parent_id which indicates the parent category of the categories you see above (eg. Cables > Network). This is my attempt to include the name of said master category:

```
***QUERY***
SELECT
  parent_name AS parent,
  categories_name AS category,
  products_model AS model,
  products_status AS status,
  products_quantity AS qty
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN categories c
ON c.categories_id = p.master_categories_id
LEFT JOIN categories_description cd
USING (categories_id)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    parent_id,
    categories_name AS parent_name
  FROM categories c
  LEFT JOIN categories_description cd
  ON cd.categories_id = c.parent_id
) par
USING (parent_id)
WHERE p.products_quantity > 0
AND p.products_status = FALSE;

***OUTPUT***
+--------------+-------------+------------------------+--------+-----+
| parent       | category    | model                  | status | qty |
+--------------+-------------+------------------------+--------+-----+
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-10-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-10-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-10-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-10-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-10-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-10-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-10-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-10-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-10-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-03-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-03-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-03-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-03-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-03-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-03-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-03-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-03-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Cables       | Network     | CP-C-03-CAT6X0         |      0 |   5 |
| Laptop Parts | Batteries   | BATT-LHP203            |      0 |   1 |
| Laptop Parts | Batteries   | BATT-LHP203            |      0 |   1 |
| Laptop Parts | Batteries   | BATT-LHP203            |      0 |   1 |
| Laptop Parts | Batteries   | BATT-LHP203            |      0 |   1 |
| Laptop Parts | Batteries   | BATT-LIB201            |      0 |   1 |
| Laptop Parts | Batteries   | BATT-LIB201            |      0 |   1 |
| Laptop Parts | Batteries   | BATT-LIB201            |      0 |   1 |
| Laptop Parts | Batteries   | BATT-LIB201            |      0 |   1 |
| Desktop PCs  | Refurbished | UC*DELL-OPT-760-DC-IBC |      0 |   9 |
| Desktop PCs  | Refurbished | UC*DELL-OPT-760-DC-IBC |      0 |   9 |
| Hard Drives  | Desktop     | HDD-320-SATA-3.5-PULL  |      0 |  12 |
| Hard Drives  | Desktop     | HDD-320-SATA-3.5-PULL  |      0 |  12 |
| Hard Drives  | Desktop     | HDD-320-SATA-3.5-PULL  |      0 |  12 |
| Hard Drives  | Desktop     | HDD-320-SATA-3.5-PULL  |      0 |  12 |
| Laptops      | Refurbished | UL*ASUS-S56CM-SH51     |      0 |   1 |
| Laptops      | Refurbished | UL*ASUS-S56CM-SH51     |      0 |   1 |
+--------------+-------------+------------------------+--------+-----+
```

As you can see, each row is duplicated multiple times. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ...` Duplicated rows are caused by joins.

Comment: Use `SELECT *` to see where your duplicate rows are comming from. The result of this query has the same rows as your query, just more attributes in each row. *But note* do not use `SELECT *` in production code.

Comment: In my experience using _joins_ is bad practice (trying to make a revolution here). You can simply go with `SELECT s.smth, h.name FROM some s, hello h WHERE s.id = h.id`

Comment: @Oswald Yeah. It was basically spitting out a row for each child category of a master category.

Comment: @Martyn That was the stupidest thing I ever heard. And what you do is, surprise, a join. It's just an older way of writing it. The join syntax was introduced since your way of writing it is very error prone, less eye friendly and so on. IIRC join syntax was introduced with the ANSI-SQL Standard from 1992, 21 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use DISTINCT to remove duplicates

SELECT DISTINCT ...

Comment: Yeah, I just realized I need to use SELECT DISTINCT in the subquery named par. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `select distinct` is a bad habit to get into.  Sometimes it is necessary, but not in this case.  Why do the extra work of removing duplicates, when it is simple enough to fix the query?

The `from` clause should look like:

```
FROM products p left join
     categories c
     ON c.categories_id = p.master_categories_id left join
     categories_description cd
     USING (categories_id) left join
     categories_description cdp
     on cdp.categories_id = c.parent_id
```

Your additional subquery not only introduces additional processing overhead, it also introduces duplicates and unnecessary query complication.